# Can we equate 2 parameters in crystal reports c# (oracle db)?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, crystal-reports

I have a simple search box in my web app and i want to provide options of searching the employee table for either name, employee id or position etc. Ie, basically a drop down and then a text box to enter the value. The columns currently being chosen are from the same table.

I have assumed i need 2 parameters equating both such that one refers to the column name and the other to its value. Is it right? And if so, how do we pass the sql query on formula editor?

Comment: I have no idea on C# but from crystal point of view you can achieve your requirement in `Record Selection Formula`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below code:

```
if ({?cat}="NAME")
then
    {FATHIMA.NAME}={?val}
else
if({?cat}="POSITION")
then
    {FATHIMA.POSITION}={?val}
```

Provided there should be value in `{?val}` and that value should match with the value in database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i have used Record Selection Formula. The code I've written there is:

```
if ({?cat}="NAME")
then
    {?val}={FATHIMA.NAME}
else
if({?cat}="POSITION")
then
    {?val}={FATHIMA.POSITION}
```

---where "NAME" and "POSITION" are column names. I have passed them manually as items in a drop down list. But the report gives an empty result. 'cat' is the parameter holding the selected value from the drop down.